# How make the gif file appear on the center of the screen

Tags: android, xml, apk

I am developing an app, which uses .gif files.
I found, how to implement a gif in Android after lot of surfing, but now the problem is. I am not able to align the gif in the center of the screen.
I tried using gravity as center.

Can anyone help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.sample.hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.sample.hello.GIFView         
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        components:src="@drawable/gifid" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this layout, to center your GIF on the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.sample.hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <com.sample.hello.GIFView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        components:src="@drawable/gifid"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a relative layout rather than linear, and put center_vertical and center_horizontal to true on the image.

Comment: Better use: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` (one attribute instead of two)

Comment: It happens to the greatest... ;)

Comment: and also i am not able to control the size of gif can anyone help me out